# Texture is being mapped wrong on a sphere using MeshBasicMaterial in IOS safari using threejs

Tags: three.js

I am using MeshBasicMaterial to map a texture to a sphere that represents a world but is being rendered wrong on IOS Safari (but is ok using chrome and safari on Mac or Windows, or Chrome on Android).

The code I am using is the following:

```
var sphereGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 32, 32);

    var earthTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '/lib/map/world/model/earth-compresed.jpg' );
    var bumpTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '/lib/map/world/model/high-bump-compresed.jpg' );
    var earthMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { 
        map: earthTexture,
        bumpMap:     bumpTexture,
        bumpScale:   1
    } );
    var earth = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeo, earthMaterial);
    scene.add(earth);
```

This is how it is shown on IOS
[image: This is how it is shown on IOS]

And this is how it must being shown and how it works everywhere else

[image: And this is how it must being shown]

Thanks

Comment: what is the size of the textures?

Comment: @gaitat 4000 × 2000px

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the textures to be powers of two (i.e. 4096x2048). In addition I would use https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/limits/gl-max-texture-dimensions.html to verify that the device supports such big textures.